# Creating a repeated loop with timed intervals in between

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to create a loop that waits 5 second before executing the next line. Here is what I have tried, after researching online:

(Please note, that I realise it won't display the image. I just want it to display the text in the alert)

```
setInterval(myMethod, 5000);

    function myMethod( )
    {
            alert('Image   https://website.com/t2EzsJj.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/TrRRE0v.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/vG8BkNG.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/uddMAhU.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/l9IpE9g.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/Lvv9S1s.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/od3robw.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/dl4HDpd.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/BJV4X1n.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/fC2HcsB.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/xtDuuGg.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/2VOBpXL.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/u3zKYpC.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/yymr6R8.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/cz8cZE0.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/rbYFSpp.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/zqAMDi9.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/Xmt84Qz.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/7wixIIK.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/Yfm3yGw.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/2DYKO6L.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/GrudZEl.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/OT115fy.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/k4bnBDa.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/tXTpcV8.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/PdkCufJ.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/NVaXfCV.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/5N69l7R.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/B2V8OKg.png')
            alert('Image   https://website.com/MOeIxJV.png')
    }
}
```

I would like the code to have a 5 second interval between each alert, so it would be like this:

```
function myMethod( )
{
        alert('Image   https://website.com/t2EzsJj.png')
        //Wait 5 seconds
        alert('Image   https://website.com/TrRRE0v.png')
        //Wait 5 seconds
        alert('Image   https://website.com/vG8BkNG.png')
        //Wait 5 seconds
        alert('Image   https://website.com/uddMAhU.png')
        //Wait 5 seconds and so on...
```

However, this code runs all the alerts instantaneously and then waits 5 seconds and runs it again.

Also, since all the alerts contain "Image https://website.com/" is there a way to make this code less redundant? Since it is being repeated a lot and just the last .png part is changing?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Hello :D, Is the number of images fixed or dynamic?

Comment: To reduce redundancy, you could store only the image IDs (so the `uddMAhU` from `https://website.com/uddMAhU.png`) in an array and the loop through the array and build the full url dynamically.

Comment: Why do you want this? The 5 seconds will be strictly theorithical, by the time the user read and closes the `alert`, the 5 seconds would be over and the next one will pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const INTERVAL_IN_MS = 5000, // 5 seconds
  imageIds = ['t2EzsJj', 'OT115fy', '5N69l7R']; // put all image IDs into this array
    
imageIds.forEach((imageId, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert(`Image https://website.com/${imageId}.png`);
  }, index * INTERVAL_IN_MS);
});
```

Every iteration of this loop will postpone a function call for `5 * index` seconds. As indices of array elements are `0, 1, 2...`, those functions will run in `0, 5, 10...` seconds. Check the [setTimeout documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

As for me `setTimeout` is simpler than `setInterval` in this case, as you won't need to `clearInterval()` in the end of the array.

To make the code less redundant, you can store an array with only image ids.

Answer (score 2):

Put your data in an `array` and use `setInterval()` to repeat through array values and use `clearInterval()` to break the loop. check below snippet for reference.

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var i = 0;
var repeat = setInterval(function() {
  if (i == cars.length) {
    clearInterval(repeat);
    return;
  }
  myFunction(i);
  i++;
}, 1000);

function myFunction() {
  console.log(cars[i]);
}
```

Comment: Forgot `myFunction`'s argument.

Comment: And by the way that's not how `clearInterval` works.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that contains image names (note that I put only 2 names, but you should fill the rest):

```
let images = ["t2EzsJj.png", "TrRRE0v.png"];
```

Now use setInterval:

```
let intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  if (images.length === 0){
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    return;
  }
  // this remove the first image from the array and return it
  let imageName = images.splice(0, 1); 
  alert(`Image   https://website.com/${imageName}`)
}, 5000)
```